# How to correctly start a Scala Project with sbt in IntelliJ?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I want to build a Scala Client that connects to the Twitter Streaming API. I created the app on Twitter to get the API and Token Keys. Now I created a new Scala Project in IntelliJ and I would like to use the OAuth2 Client from https://index.scala-lang.org/dakatsuka/akka-http-oauth2-client/akka-http-oauth2-client/0.2.0?target=_2.12

What is the correct way of proceeding? I inserted the dependency statement in the `build.sbt` file:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.dakatsuka" %% "akka-http-oauth2-client" % "0.1.0"
```

and added the import statement at the top of the class:

```
import java.net.URI
import com.github.dakatsuka.akka.http.oauth2.client.{ Client, Config }

object Client extends App {


    val config = Config(
        clientId     = "..."
        clientSecret = "..."
        site         = URI.create("api.twitter.com")
    )

    val client = Client(config)

    // for the moment nothing else
}
```

Is this correct and what do I need to do such that it obtaines the dakatsuka library?

EDIT to follow up on comment

According to [the documentation:](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html)

[image]

I enter `reload` and then `update` at the `sbt shell` prompt but when I do that it returns:

```
IJ]sbt:stream_scala> update
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last update for the full output
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.github.dakatsuka:akka-http-oauth2-client_2.13:0.2.0
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /home/mzh/.ivy2/local/com.github.dakatsuka/akka-http-oauth2-client_2.13/0.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/dakatsuka/akka-http-oauth2-client_2.13/0.2.0/akka-http-oauth2-client_2.13-0.2.0.pom
[error]   not found: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/dakatsuka/akka-http-oauth2-client_2.13/0.2.0/akka-http-oauth2-client_2.13-0.2.0.pom
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Jul 6, 2020, 7:36:08 PM
[IJ]sbt:stream_scala>
```

The Sonatype Resolver is there:

```
[IJ]sbt:stream_scala> inspect resolvers
[info] Setting: scala.collection.Seq[sbt.librarymanagement.Resolver] = Vector(Sonatype OSS Snapshots: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots)
[info] Description:
[info]  The user-defined additional resolvers for automatically managed dependencies.
```

My `build.sbt` looks like this:

```
name := "stream_scala"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.3"

resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.dakatsuka" %% "akka-http-oauth2-client" % "0.2.0"
```

Comment: Does it fails? If so what kind of failure it was, a compile-time one or a runtime one? If a compile-time one what was the error message? If a runtime one, did you get an exception or did the code produced a different result? Again, which was the exception message? in case you get an exception, or if code misbehave what did it do, what did you  expected it to do?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Added more details to the question.

Comment: Could you add your full `build.sbt` or at least relevant parts like **Scala** version, and all dependencies. Also, it would be good to mention which **SBT** version your project uses and if you have any plugins.

Comment: Ah forget it, the error is pretty _"simple"_ but you will not like the answer. You are using a library that is only published for **Scala** `2.11` & `2.12` but your project is using **Scala** `2.13`, so **SBT** doesn't find an appropriate jar. Anyways, that library hasn't been updated since 2017... I would suggest searching for something newer instead.

Comment: I see, yes that seems to help, gonna try https://github.com/DanielaSfregola/twitter4s

Comment: Sorry but no. I haven't done that before. If you can find anything scala related, you can always use java libraries in **Scala**, and I would guess that Twitter has its own official java library. What you can do is write a small wrapper over the java library so its usage is more scala-like.